# How can I add 'on', 'off' label to mat-slide-toggle?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Right now, I have a slide-toggle like this:

```
<mat-slide-toggle
    class="toggle">
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

[image]

How can I add `on`, `off` label like below?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hack this with CSS, but it's really hacky. In your host wrapper component .scss:

```
:host {
  .mat-slide-toggle {
    &.mat-checked {
      ::ng-deep.mat-slide-toggle-bar::after {
        content: 'ON';
        font-size: 45%;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        left: 4px;
        top: -5px;
      }
    }
    &:not(.mat-checked) {
      ::ng-deep.mat-slide-toggle-bar::after {
        content: 'OFF';
        font-size: 45%;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        left: 21px;
        top: -5px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xc3iyc?file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.scss)

Comment: That's way more lightweight than creating a custom control. You can use `ng-deep` now by using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none` in the `@Component` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Angular material components are not build to be extendable
check: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10208

Instead you can create your own custom form field
check: https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control